# How to DUPLICATE a dual boot SSD (to a larger SSD)?

Tags: ssd, dualboot

I've finally got my system EXACTLY the way I want it.

MacBook 2012 - internal 500GB SSD running Mojave and Windows 7 (nothing to do with "bootcamp", just a separate bootable partition - I press the option key at startup and tell the machine which OS I want it to boot)

So, I want to DUPLICATE this system in another 2012 MacBook (getting prepared because it's just a matter of time until this one dies and I occasionally buy second-hand 2012s so that I can keep working the way I want to instead of the way Apple wants me to..)

As far as I know I can't just clone the drive and expect to have both partitions bootable (or can I?? Let me know 'cos that would be rad!!)

The main thing I'm looking for help with is the idea of cloning only a 'partition' on one drive to only a 'partition' on the other drive (leaving the rest of the drive the hell alone..)

Also, I want the partitions to be twice the size on the new drive..

So, to summarise:

DUPLICATE:

Mojave (250GB Partition) / Windows 7 (250GB Partition) on 500GB SSD

to

Mojave (500GB Partition) / Windows 7 (500GB Partition) on 1TB SSD

(with both OSs bootable as they are now.)

How hard can it be....? ;)

Answer (score 1):

*I know we don't seem to like product requests on here, but the OP didn't ask for a product rec & these are industry standard go-to tools on Mac.*

[WinClone](https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/winclone/) is the 'surest' way to move the Win partition. [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com) can do both partitions, but needs the partitions setting up manually first. [Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-mac/) *might* be able to do it, but it's something I've never tested. I think all come with a free trial.
None of them will damage your existing drive, so you can play about with each of them until you're happy.
I'd have a good read through the documentation for each - you might get one tool to do the whole lot, or have to share the task between two or more.

Smarter people than me might be able to do it with `dd`.